# What can I do to fix questions that can't be improved without major changes?

Tags: discussion, questions, edits

I've run into a couple of questions in the past few days involving concepts that I'd love to see answered, but the questions themselves are written extremely badly. They tend to be littered with grammatical mistakes, ambiguous as to what the question actually asks, and are more or less incomprehensible.

I believe that questions like this will never receive good answers, because to provide one would require additional clarification from the author—something that, given the quality of the question, I think either will never come or, if it does, not provide much help.

Trying to understand the meaning of and rework the question through heavy editing and content addition is a risky step, because to significantly improve the clarity of the problem an editor must specify what they *think* the original author meant. Doing so runs the risk of deviating from the author's initial intentions, which **might be impossible to determine.** I believe that this is why I've been rejected [both](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2004792) of the [times](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2173889) I have tried to make (what I thought to be) major improvements to a question. Although I consider my edits to provide higher-quality questions but still cover what the original authors *probably* meant, the assumptions I had to make which resulted in that "probably" were **too dangerous to the original questions to accept.** My point isn't anything to do with those specific edits (besides, I could have made more mistakes that I'm missing); rather, my inspiration for them.

I would like to see these questions get answered, but I highly doubt that they will be in their current state, and if they are, their low level of quality will help few but the original author. **How should I address questions with concepts I love but executions that can't be saved without major revising?**

All I've been able to come up with so far is to ask my own, higher-quality version of the question, although I feel as if I'd be somehow infringing on the original.

Comment: If there is no certainty about the original intent then I'd just comment inviting the OP to improve the meaning.

Comment: Comment or close them. If a question "cannot be reasonably answered in its current form," and there's no obvious way to improve it, then either comment, or just close it as not a real question. If you are interested in the concepts, though, feel free to post your own question!